# Relationship between the inverse of a matrix function $A(x)$ and the inverse of the derivative of that matrix $\frac{dA}{dx}$

Tags: matrices, derivatives, inverse, matrix-calculus

Given an arbitrary matrix function $A(x)$ of dimension $3 \times 3$.

Is there any relationship between the inverse of this matrix and the inverse of the derivative of this matrix, which would allow one to judge the invertibility of the derivative of this matrix by the invertibility of the original matrix?

$A(x)^{-1} \longleftrightarrow [\frac{dA(x)}{dx}]^{-1}$

Comment: Do you mean a linear function $x\mapsto Ax$ where $A$ is a matrix or a matrix, that depends on a parameter $x$ like $$\begin{pmatrix}x & 0\\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$$ or like a rotation matrix?

Comment: @Wurstcake Yes, I meant a matrix of an arbitrary structure depending on a parameter, not a rotation matrix.

Comment: But matrices dependent on a parameter $x$?

Comment: Yes, I mean any matrix in the forms $[x,1;-5,x^2]$ or $[x-6,x,1;4,12,sin(x);-7,-x,5]$ for example

Comment: @dtn No, you cannot infer the invertibility of $\frac{dA}{dx}$ from the invertibility of $A$ itself. Wurstcake has provided a nice counter-example.

Comment: @greg I would say that this is not a counterexample, but a direct demonstration of the fact that in some cases the information connecting two matrices is simply lost. Apparently, the only option at the moment is to treat these two matrices as unrelated to each other.